# When does a mysql session end in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions

I have a mysql database (InnoDB engine) where I lock a few tables before doing some work. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)

> *"The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with transactional tables, such as InnoDB tables, is to begin a transaction with SET autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION) followed by LOCK TABLES, and to not call UNLOCK TABLES until you commit the transaction explicitly."*

So I'm doing (pseudocode):

```
mysqli_query("SET autocommit=0");
mysqli_query("LOCK TABLES table1 WRITE, table2 READ ...");
mysqli_query("SOME SELECTS AND INSERTS HERE");
mysqli_query("COMMIT");
mysqli_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

Now, should I also do this:

```
mysqli_query("SET autocommit=1");
```

According to the documentation again,

> *"When you call LOCK TABLES, InnoDB internally takes its own table lock, and MySQL takes its own table lock. InnoDB releases its internal table lock at the next commit, but for MySQL to release its table lock, you have to call UNLOCK TABLES. You should not have autocommit = 1, because then InnoDB releases its internal table lock immediately after the call of LOCK TABLES, and deadlocks can very easily happen. InnoDB does not acquire the internal table lock at all if autocommit = 1, to help old applications avoid unnecessary deadlocks."*

I think the documentation is a bit ambigous at this point. As I'm interpreting it, you shouldn't use `SET autocommit=1` in place of `UNLOCK TABLES`.

However, there shouldn't be any harm in doing it AFTER the tables have been unlocked?

But still I'm unsure if it's necessary. I have a single select running in the same script after the COMMIT, and it appears to autocommit even if I don't `SET autocommit=1`. Why?

Comment: What else follows your "mysqli_query("UNLOCK TABLES");"
Do you CLOSE the connection?  
If you are finished when the next sessions starts, the autocommit will be inherited from the global value setting, this would seem to be unnecessary if your activity is completed.
This URL is unrelated by does have examples of close the connection.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: It's a 3 year old question, and I changed the whole logic a while after I asked the question. So it's not really relevant for me anymore. Thanks anyway :)